# How to update a slider on a bunch of table cells continuously?

Tags: ios, swift, download, tableview, nsurlsession

The first method I tried caused an error due to disrupting layout, but basically here my issue: In have a tableview whose cells all have sliders/progress views. The value on these sliders needs to equal the attached item (I assign RSS items to each cell, its music)'s percent that it has downloaded, if the user tapped to download it.

I am calling this func in the observer for the download progress here:

```
//DOWNLOAD PROGRESS
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {
    let progress = Double(totalBytesWritten) / Double(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
    print("\(downloadTask.originalRequest!.url!.absoluteString) \(progress)")

    updateListCells()
}
```

Here is how I try to update my cells so that the user could see the progress bar gradually growing - I have subclassed the cells:

```
func updateListCells()
{
    if let table = listVC.myTableView {
        if(!table.visibleCells.isEmpty)
        {
            for v in table.visibleCells {
                let cell = v as! RSSTableViewCell
                cell.updateLoader()
            }
        }
    }
}

func updateLoader()
    {
        self.bringSubview(toFront: downloadLoader)
        if(pathUrl != nil)
        {
            if(checkIfExists(url: pathUrl!))
            {
                downloadLoader.progress = 1
            }
            else {
                for d in downloadManager.operations {
                    if(URL(string: rssItem.link) == d.value.task.originalRequest?.url)
                    {
                        let progress = Double(d.value.task.countOfBytesReceived) / Double(d.value.task.countOfBytesExpectedToReceive)
                        //print("MATCH: ", d.value.task.countOfBytesSent)
                        downloadLoader.progress = Float(progress)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            downloadLoader.progress = 0
        }
    }
```

but this doesn't work continuously. Only if I refresh the tableview does the slider assume its current download value.

How can I update the tableview cells continuously if download is happening?

Comment: Not sure, but maybe running this "downloadLoader.progress = Float(progress)" in the main thread will work?

Comment: what do you mean? It would have to get set to the slider repeatedly, and Im not going to set a timer to do it over and over or something

Answer (score 0):

You should run updateListCells() in the main thread (as @arvidurs wrote):

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {
    let progress = Double(totalBytesWritten) / Double(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
    print("\(downloadTask.originalRequest!.url!.absoluteString) \(progress)")
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.updateListCells()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, was on the road.

Comment: Not working. Just clears off all the other cells that aren't being downloaded, and doesn't download smoothly